# File download from URL stops when multiple clients try to download it

Tags: java

I'm creating a "patcher launcher" for my game which automatically downloads the latest version of the game when you launch it. However when more than one person tries to download the file at the same time, everyone's download freezes and stops and will only resume when everyone else closes their downloaded and only 1 is downloading at a time. Anyone can help? Here is the current code I use to download files from URL.

```
public void saveUrl(String filename, String urlString)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Downloading " + urlString);
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;

    int currentdlsize = 0;
    int dlsize = new URL(urlString).openConnection().getContentLength();
    System.out.println("DL Size " + dlsize);

    in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString).openStream());
    fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    int count;
    while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
        fout.write(data, 0, count);
        currentdlsize += count;
        System.out.println("Downloaded " + currentdlsize + "/" + dlsize);
        prog.setMaximum(dlsize);
        prog.setValue(currentdlsize);
        progstat.setText("Downloading at " + currentdlsize + "/" + dlsize);
    }

    in.close();
    fout.close();

    System.out.println("Downloaded to " + filename);
}
```

Comment: what are the server side you are using ?

Comment: Make sure that in case any of the exceptions is thrown, you will be aware of it. It's not possible to tell this from this method because it simply throws the exceptions on to the next upper level of invocation and we can not see how that code handles exceptions.

Comment: There is nothing special over on the server side, its just a normal Apache file server I guess. I'm not too knowledgeable in this area, but basically I just upload the game JARs to my website and get the patcher to download from there. Also there are no exceptions thrown, the downloading just 'pauses' for everyone and only resumes when everyone else exits the application and you're the only person downloading.

Answer (score 2):

Your download code looks ok and I do not see any reason for a race condition, so without deeper analysis of your download code, I can tell you that this code (client side) is not the problem. It must be the server side which causes the problem, i.e. your webserver or a proxy or firewall which is in between.

Moreover, maybe you should look at [JNLP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html), which is a technology designed exactly for your problem of keeping an application always updated and checking this at startup.

Comment: I somehow managed to solve the issue by removing:
int dlsize = new URL(urlString).openConnection().getContentLength();

but however now I do not know of any other way to get the file size of the download, any other way I could go about doing so?

Comment: You were opening two connections by doing that. You should call `URL.openConnection()` to get a single `HttpURLConnection` object, and then get the content-length and the input stream from that object.